# max os x split view resize window with keyboard?

Tags: macos

Is there a keyboard shortcut in El Capitan to resize the windows in Split View ? I know I can use the mouse for this, but I would be happy If I although can use the keyboard for this.

Comment: I suggest that you delete this question and ask it on superuser.com, since it will probably be closed here (it's not related to programming, which is what SO is about).

Comment: Check Amethyst, they promised split screen support

Answer (score 0):

doesn't seem like this is an option according to the apple support site : https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204948 and everything I've tried :p If this is an important feature, there is a payware with keyboard shortcuts, http://splitscreenapp.com/